# Benchmarking a HTTP server

Tags: c++, http, networking, benchmarking

I'm currently building a custom C++-based HTTP server whose purpose is to serve HTTP GET requests as fast as possible.

I'd like to throw some test at it in order to check that the server behaves correctly when a lot of clients (~1000) are requesting content at the same time. And I'm wondering if there was any tool that could help me in that regard.

I'd like to measure the time my server takes to respond to each request and the time it takes for each client to receive the complete reply. I could build up my own application that does the job, but I was wondering if something like that already existed.

As this is my first network-based application, I was also wondering what kind of limitations I was to expect when running that kind of tests over a Gigabit network, if any.

Comment: Off topic, of course (software recommendation, not programming). That said, a serious HTTP server can handle several 10G connections. Thus the limitation of a 1G network is that it's **wayy** too slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a load generator. The best configuration is if you have the target system (system you want to test) in one machine and the load generator in other machine. Both machines in the same LAN. If you have target system and load generator in the same machine, the load generator could grab resources from the target system.

I would use [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) or [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/). JMeter is easy to install and use. The only problem is that it represents virtual clients as threads. Each virtual client means one thread and that could use lots of system resources if you one to simulate 1K virtual clients. Tsung simulates many virtual clients with the same thread and thus, it can consume less resources.

Comment: Tsungs seems to be what I was looking for, thanks ^^

As a side note, I also found [this project](https://github.com/mtourne/gurl) to test the SPDY part of my server.

Answer (score 1):

[jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) is a java based tool which can configure to do load testing.